# In REACTJS webpack5 not load css and styling when run npm run serve

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

**I have tried multiple solutions like style-loader in css test case but its not working. Below I have uploaded my files and screenshots of code structure as well as obtained output and desired output**.

**Any kind of help is appreciated.**

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/",
    clean: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".*", ".js", ".jsx", ".css"],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },

      {
        test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,

        use: ["css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpe?g|svg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|otf|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 1000,
              name: "assets/img/[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),
    }),
  ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nazox",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.7.0",
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.5.0",
    "@lourenci/react-kanban": "^2.1.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.7",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dialogs": "^5.13.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "1.6.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "^21.1.41",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@toast-ui/react-chart": "^1.0.2",
    "@vtaits/react-color-picker": "^0.1.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.17.0",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap-react-treetable": "^2.0.2",
    "broadcast-channel": "^4.18.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "compressorjs": "^1.1.1",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dompurify": "^2.3.10",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.4",
    "echarts": "^4.7.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.15-beta.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "filerobot-image-editor": "^3.12.17",
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "fontkit": "^2.0.2",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.3",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",
    "html-to-image": "^1.11.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "i18next": "^19.4.5",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.2.0",
    "json-to-csv-export": "^2.1.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lottie-react": "^2.3.1",
    "mdbreact": "^4.25.4",
    "metismenujs": "^1.1.0",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nouislider-react": "^3.3.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^3.3.122",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.6",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
    "react-avatar": "^4.0.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^7.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-editable": "^0.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.1.9",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-editor": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.2",
    "react-chartist": "^0.14.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-circle-slider": "^1.6.2",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-corner-ribbon": "0.0.5",
    "react-countdown": "^2.2.1",
    "react-cropper": "^1.3.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-custom-checkbox": "^2.0.1",
    "react-customizable-progressbar": "^1.0.3",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
    "react-export-table-to-excel": "^1.0.6",
    "react-filerobot-image-editor": "^4.3.7",
    "react-flatpickr": "^3.10.7",
    "react-gauge-chart": "^0.4.1",
    "react-google-invisible-recaptcha": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.7",
    "react-grid-carousel": "^1.0.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.9",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
    "react-images": "^1.2.0-beta.7",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-jvectormap": "^0.0.16",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.5",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.1.0",
    "react-minimal-side-navigation": "^1.9.2",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.7",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.2.3",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.4.0",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.3.3",
    "react-pdf": "4.0.5",
    "react-pdf-to-image": "^1.0.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "react-rating": "^2.0.5",
    "react-rating-tooltip": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-search-autocomplete": "^5.4.4",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select-search": "^3.0.9",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
    "react-star-ratings": "^2.3.0",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.4",
    "react-toastr": "^3.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "rsuite": "^5.24.1",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.3",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "url-exist": "^3.0.0",
    "url-exists": "^1.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "use-gauge": "^0.6.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "webpack": "^5.82.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack serve",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.0",
    "npm": "8.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.8.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.25",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.80.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  }
}
```

**Inside public folder assets is given and this screenshot shows the theme styling files**

[image: scss files inside assets folders]

> **I am getting this output**

[image]

> **Desired Output**

[image]

**Styles file 1**

[image]

**Styles file 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an old 11ty template that was using webpack4. To get around this, I used `mini-css-extract-plugin` in my dev webpack.

According [to the docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#recommend), `style-loader` should be used for dev, but since I'm only using a static site, the `mini-css-extract-plugin` worked pretty easy for my needs.

Not sure if this is recommended, but worked for my needs - hope it works for yours.

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/",
    clean: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".*", ".js", ".jsx", ".css"],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },

      {
        test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,

        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpe?g|svg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|otf|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 1000,
              name: "assets/img/[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/style.css"
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks @leon.io. But this solution is not worked for me

Comment: then perhaps the path is incorrect, which path/files are getting a 404 from the developer tab. That should indicate where the index page is trying to retrieve styles from. Then you'll just need to modify the path in `MiniCssExtractPlugin.filename` to output the styles there.

Comment: I am not getting your point. I have edit the question and upload style files structure. Please take an insight.